# How to make code await work if both cases?

Tags: dart

I have got flow code:

```
Future<void> addResultToCache(sqlQuery) async {

  List<RequestCacheStruct> requestsList = [];
  List<int> pendingRequestList = []; 

    if(!pendingRequestList.contains(sqlQuery.hashCode))
    {
      pendingRequestList.add(sqlQuery.hashCode);
      var queryResult = await connection.query(sqlQuery, timeoutInSeconds: 3600); // here
      var queryObj = RequestCacheStruct(sqlQuery.hashCode, DateTime.now(), queryResult );
      requestsList.add(queryObj);
      pendingRequestList.removeWhere((element) => element == sqlQuery.hashCode);
      print('Query was added to Cache');
    }
    else {
      print("This query is already running");
    }

}
```

In `if` block code is awaiting `query` result:

```
var queryResult = await connection.query(sqlQuery, timeoutInSeconds: 3600);
```

But if executing `else` block:

```
var foo = await addResultToCache(...);
```

will return wrong result because it will end before query is completed.

Comment: You need to maintain a `Map` from pending queries to associated `Future`s.  If a query is already pending, `await` the existing `Future` along the`else` path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want multiple requests for the same asynchronous operation to be coalesced into an existing operation that's already pending, typically you should maintain, say, a `Map` that associates pending operations with their corresponding `Future`s.  If you determine that an operation is already pending, `await` the existing `Future`.   For example:

```dart
final pendingOperations = <int, Future<Result>>{};

Future<Result> someAsyncOperation(int requestId) async {
  if (pendingOperations.containsKey(requestId)) {
    return await pendingOperations[requestId]!;
  } else {
    var future = doActualWork();
    pendingOperations[requestId] = future;
    var result = await future;
    pendingOperations.remove(requestId);
    return result;
  }
}
```